# How to specify "any word" in route?

Tags: laravel

I want to attach the following action to /articles/<any word>/{article}.html :

```
public function show(Article $article)
{
   return $this->doShow($article);
}
```

If I use wildcard (in place of <any word>) - for example {catalogue} - Laravel inserts it to action's arguments, which is undesirable. I tried * symbol, ':any', ':any?" - the route just stops working (I get 404). What should I use?

Comment: That's the default behaviour. If you want to change it, you can try the approach suggested in this [comment](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/9592#issuecomment-120654619).

Comment: @Camilo huh, that doesn't look good/simple. I still hope there is a better solution.

Comment: I don't think its worth the effort either. I would add the `$anyWord` parameter to the `show()` method, I don't see what's the problem with that.

Answer (score 3):

Routes do not always have to be bound to a model. If a route parameter is not bound to a model the string will be sent to the controller.

"Laravel inserts it to action's arguments, which is undesirable" This is the expected behavior, but you do not have to use the variable if you don't need it. But if that's the case you should reconsider your URL scheme.

```
Route::get('/articles/{term}/{article}.html', 'ArticleController@show');

public function show($term, Article $article)
{
   // $term will be a string wish whichever value is in the {term} section
   // $article will be the model that matches the key in the {article} section
   return $this->doShow($article);
}
```

Comment: Why must I specify  extra argument in my action? I just don't need that value and don't want to modify all my actions for such purposes.

Comment: @Audiophile Why do you want an unused wildcard in your route? If your app returns the same page for both '/articles/cat1/article1.html' and '/articles/cat2/article1.html` then it will mess up your SEO and is an indicator of bad design.

Comment: I use unique article name so I don't need catalogue name in "show" action. I also have /articles/cat/article.html/add_comment and other actions attached to such URLs and I don't want to specify unneeded arguments for all of them.

Comment: You have to capture that {term} anyhow, weather you use it or not in your controller is irrelevant... this solution works...

Comment: @Audiophile I would recommend rethinking how you design your routes. You are going to have problems with SEO. Also `.html` is unneeded and can cause confusion in your `add_comment` route.